# Update user in one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create app to update user info, but when I first click on edit button my app auto delete my current info and render my current view then i must click again to go edit view. My problem is, I just want to go edit view in one click.So, please help me.

This is in my user view.

```
<%= link_to "edit", welcome_edit_path(@user)%>
```

This is in my edit view

```
<div class="medium-4 medium-centered row">
    <div class="medium-10 medium-centered columns">
        <h3>Edit</h3> 
        <%= form_tag(:controller =>"welcome", :action => "edit", :method => "post") do %>
        Avatar<%= file_field_tag(:image)%>
        <%= submit_tag("Save", class: "button [tiny small large]")%>
        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.assign_attributes(:image => params[:image])
    if @user.changed?
      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
    end
  end
```

My routes

```
  get '/welcome/edit/:id', to: 'welcome#edit', as: 'welcome_edit'
  match '/welcome/edit/:id', to: 'welcome#edit', via: 'post'
```

I think something wrong in my controller or my routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are intending to do such behaviour, But what takes you to the profile is the `redirect_to @user`, you don't need to render anything

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.assign_attributes(:image => params[:image])
  @user.save if @user.changed?
end
```

Comment: I want to redirect_to @user after changing image, because I change image in edit view not in my user view.I try your code but it's still in edit view. May be, i should create a new link in edit view to go back user view. Sorry! if my english so bad :)

Comment: @mayoneQD is that what you wanted? are you changing questions?

Comment: yeah my problem has been solved, but i can't go back to user now. May be i should try a different way. thank you!